# Moving Columns To Rows In User-Selected Range With VBA Script

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA script that would allow me to select a range of data, and then, skipping the first column in the range, move the values the succeeding columns under the first column.

#### Screenshot of my Excel worksheet with annotations

[image: Screenshot of my Excel worksheet with annotations]

I need my script to allow me to select a range. Based on that range, if the first column is not null, the values of the remaining columns on that row, if they are not null, need to be copied and pasted special (transposed) below the first column of the row.

I am beating my brain over the best way to loop through the range, but here is my script code so far:

```
Sub ColsToRows()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

For Each Row In rng
    If Not IsNull(rng.Row) Then
        ActiveCell.Resize(1, 4).Copy
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Why am I getting a selection error ("This selection is not valid...")?

Comment: Have you tried a loop to go through each row one at a time, copy the data, then Paste Special->Transpose into a new sheet with the same layout under Column 1?

Comment: It will be somewhat easier if you copy all the cells into a single column outside of the original range. (It can still be done the way you want, just maybe easier this way.) Looks like you want the results sorted in a specific manner, so in your initial loop, just copy the cells as you encounter them in the range, then sort the resulting column the way you want it.

Comment: @TheGuyThatDoesn'tKnowMuch I am attempting a solution, at least, similar to what you've suggested, but I am getting a runtime error on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that was finally concocted to achieve what I was trying to achieve:

```
Sub PhotoColumnsToRows()

Dim i As Long 'row counter
Dim j As Long 'URL counter - For counting amount of URLs to add
Dim LRow As Long 'last row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn screen updating off to stop flickering

LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'determine current last row

i = 2 'start at row 2

Do While i < LRow

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) = False Then 'checks column K for data

        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 13))) 'counts amount of Urls between K and M

        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + j).Insert 'insert amount of rows found from countA
        Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 11 + j - 1)).Copy 'copies specific range based on CountA
        Cells(i + 1, 10).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 'pastespecial transpose below "J"
        Range(Cells(i, 11), Cells(i, 11 + j - 1)).ClearContents 'clear previously copied data
        LRow = LRow + j 'increments last row by the number of rows added


    End If

    i = i + 1 'increment loop
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn back on screen updating

End Sub
```